# What does PDF Version 1.x refer to?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

What is the meaning of the File Property PDF Version 1.x ?

Is the PDF File on version 1.x (or) the PDF Reader software takes only 1.x version files?

In addition, how can we convert PDF Files with lower PDF Version to latest PDF Version files?

Comment: Why is "convert PDF Files with lower PDF Version to latest PDF Version files" important for you?

Answer (score 2):

#### The Meaning of PDF Version

According to the PDF specification:

> The PDF version number identifies a specific version of the PDF specification. A PDF file is labelled with the version number of the PDF specification that the file conforms to.

*(ISO 32000-2, I.2 "PDF version numbers")*

#### PDFs with Which Versions Shall a PDF Processor Accept?

> A PDF processor shall attempt to read any PDF file, even if the file’s version is more recent than that for which the PDF processor was created.

*(ISO 32000-2, I.2 "PDF version numbers")*

#### Converting PDF Files with Lower PDF Version to Latest PDF Version Files

First of all, you usually don't need to do that as PDF processors are expected to try and process arbitrary PDFs.

If you really want to increase the claimed version number of a PDF, though, you can add an incremental update to the PDF and add the desired version as value of the **Version** entry of the **Catalog**.

(You could also change the version number in the file header and a probably existing **Version** entry of the **Catalog** but if the PDF is signed, this will break the signature for good.)

Answer (score 0):

The x is a placeholder for the minor value of the PDF version. For example instead of saying 1.3, 1.4, and 1.6 one will just say 1.x.

Until recently and for all practical purposes, the only PDFs you are going to encounter are version 1.x.